# How can i import an image sequence with transparent background (no smooth) on Blender 2.91.0?

Tags: import, video-sequence-editor, transparency, frame-rate

I need to import a short image sequence (PNG) that has alpha channel to Blender (Eevee) on the version 2.91.0, also selecting the frame rate (30 on this case)
I'm planning to use the Emission node for not losing brightnes/color of the image when having it working.
How can i do this? i'm a little lost since i used older versions of Blender and this changed a lot.
Also, maybe my 'clip' is working but not showing when i press 'play' on the timeline, do i need to activate something else?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The framerate for the clip depends on the project's framerate.

Comment: what do you mean by "no smooth"?

Comment: @HISEROD like not having any kind of anisotropic filtering on it, just the 'plain' image being rendered.